How to use inspect to get the callee's info from caller in Python?
When a method makes a call to several callees within itself, is there a way to use the inspect module to get or log the immediate callees of the called method?
I tried using inspect.getouterframes() but that seems to reproduce the behavior of traceback.print_stack() What I want is the opposite. I asked chat GPT why I cannot use inspect.getinnerframes for my purpose, and it said that is not suitable for my purpose of dynamic immediate callee logging. I do believe, however, that inspect.getinnerframes is one of the keys to the solution.

So what happens when you use inspect.getinnerframes?

Don't trust ChatGPT. It is prone to producing plausible-sounding nonsense.

Can you give a code example that illustrates what information you're trying to retrieve exactly? Are you trying to determine what functions could possibly be called from a specific frame? Or what functions have been called previously (and returned)?

@pppery although your remark is true in general, there's not enough evidence here to say if it was wrong in this case. It's unclear what OP's exact purpose is, and it's quite possible that the response from ChatGPT is in fact correct, and OP cannot get what they want from inspect.getinnerframes(). Just blurting out a random platitude like that is not helpful, unless you know it's actually relevant.
